# Web Image Scraping with PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, web-scraping, qtwebkit

I would like to build a web scraping utility designed to capture images as they were intended to be viewed.  Some images contain a transparency layer and thus are designed to be viewed in front of a specific color or textured background. For such images I would like to take a screenshot, but cropped to just the image being scraped so that the image is captured with its associated background.

I'm looking at QtWebKit module for PyQt.  For those who are familiar, would this module fit my needs?  Or perhaps would a different library or utility be better suited for this task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Image Scraping - Handling CSS and Transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783957/web-image-scraping-handling-css-and-transparency)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/).  I picture the workflow being to use phantomjs to capture the entire page, as well as capture the data of the image position and size.  Then use PIL (or even just GraphicsMagick) to crop the capture page down to just that image.

PhantomJS is programmed in javascript, but you should only need a few lines of JS code to load the page, find the image in it to query the size and position and snap the capture.

EDIT (in response to comment): Sure.  You can use jQuery, or other tools of your choice.  Here is a short example of phantomjs to open a page and get the size/position of an image in the page:

```
 var page = require('webpage').create();
 page.open(URL, function(status) {
   var img_attr = page.evaluate(function(){
            var el = $("img#SpecialID");
            var result = el.offset();  // Returns top, left
            result.width = el.width();
            result.height = el.height();
            return result;
        });
   console.log(img_attr);  //Obviously, you'd want to write that to disk instead
   page.render(OUTPUT_FILE);
  });
```

So, if you fix up the console.log to write a record to disk, and add command line options for URL and OUTPUT_FILE, as well as maybe some error handling, and you will have a handy utility to call from your Python code.

Comment: PhantomJS looks interesting, although I'd ideally like to work in pure Python.  Would it be a simple task to crawl the DOM for images with specific properties and query the size/position using PhantomJS?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you `spynner` while you are using [python](/questions/tagged/python) =)

```
import spynner

browser = spynner.Browser()
browser.load("http://www.wordreference.com")
browser.snapshot( .... )
browser.close()
```

See https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner